# How is Cu(OH)2 a base if it can't dissolve in water?

Tags: acid-base

As the title says, how is **$\ce{Cu(OH)2}$** a base if it can't dissolve in water?

I mean if it can't dissolve in water then it won't produce any **$\ce{OH-}$** ions.

And if it won't produce any **$\ce{OH-}$** ions then how can it be called a base?

Same question for **$\ce{Fe(OH)2}$** and every other base which is not an alkali.

I feel like this question is quite obvious and don't know how to describe it more. So please help.

Comment: You are using the Arrhenius definition of acids and bases, which only applies to substances that dissolve in water. The Bronsted-Lowry and Lewis definitions don't require water, so insoluble hydroxides can still be bases under these definitions.

Comment: oh, thx. Another question. My teacher gave us a question- "What happens when HCl gas is exposed to dry litmus paper". The answer was -"no reaction". Why is that so?

Comment: [confusion-about-ph-of-a-substance](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/55809/confusion-about-ph-of-a-substance/) - I had mentioned why things are acidic and why they aren't.

Comment: Dry HCl cannot dissociate and hence it won't be acidic. You need a medium such as water for HCl to dissociate. Acidic property shows up when there are free $H^{+}$ ions.

Comment: can it dissocciate when the weather is humid?

Comment: @Adi Yes it will but you do not even need a humid weather. Traces of water are enough.

Comment: Dry HCl is a nasty thing. It will suck water out of air, even if there is very little of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Copper (II) hydroxide has some small solubility in water, determined by its solubility product constant.  More importantly, it will dissolve freely and act as a base if a suitable acid, such as acetic acid, is is available to be neutralized.  See also the comment from @f".